# This site can’t provide a secure connection asp.net core desde linux

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

Buen dia, actualmente estoy desarrollando una API utilizando asp.net core 2.1. Cuando utilizo el ide visual studio 2019 en windows no tengo problemas para correr el proyecto pero ahora que estoy utilizando linux y hago la compilacion por consola utilizando dotnet tengo este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la mayoria de soluciones que he visto las hacen utilizando el framework o cambiando opciones dentro del IDE visual studio asi que no puedo implementarla en mi proyecto. He intentado agregando:

```
.UseSetting("https_port", "5000")
```

dentro de program.cs pero no ha funcionado.

mi clase program.cs es el siguiente:

```
public class Program
{



    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
        RunSeeding(host);//esta llamando el alimentador de la base de datos
        host.Run();
    }

    private static void RunSeeding(IWebHost host)
    {
        var scopeFactory = host.Services.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
        using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var seeder = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<SeedDb>();
            seeder.SeedAsync().Wait();
        }
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSetting("https_port", "5000")
            .UseStartup<Startup>();

}
```

}

mi clase configure.cs

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();                


        app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas agregar nada en tu program, almenos para solucionar el problema que tienes. El problema es que Kestrel utiliza 2 puertos al correr la aplicación, uno para las conexiones http que es el 5000 y otro para https 5001. Debería funcionarte bien por https://localhost:5001

Comment: Si, y ademas recuerda configurar el certificado local por si no se genero al correr por primera vez la solución.